# apache php5-fpm 404 error on chroot enable

Tags: apache, php, ubuntu-14.04, chroot

I know this particular question has been asked many times but i don't see any solving answers.

I have a mod_proxy_fcgi + php5-fpm + apache 2.4 configured on UBUNTU 14 its working **perfectly fine**.

i wanted to make php-fpm **chrooted** (So users wont access other users resource in shared env) if config:

```
prefix = /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/ 
chroot = $prefix 
chdir = /
```

After config: if i access php script in browser i get 404 error "File not found"

If i COMMENT this above chroot config then php works again without any errors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Freenod Channel #php-fpm person named "Kiranos" helped me to solve the problem.

My setup was: `Apache 2.4.7 + mod_proxy_fcgi + php5-fpm on Ubuntu 14.04`

The problem was, i had TCP connection to php-fpm socket in vhost like

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/example.net/public_html/$1
```

and in php-fpm pool conf i had

```
chroot = /var/www/html/example.net/public_html/
```

**Note:** Since Apache 2.4.7 don't support unix socket connection i had to use TCP. While using TCP there is no need to mention complete doc path in ProxyPassMatch for chrooting.

**Wrong Conf in vHost:**

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/example.net/public_html/$1
```

**Correct Conf in vHost:**

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/$1
```

After doing this chroot was working..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if a chroot is the perfect solution. A chroot not automaticly means a better security. A better way is to run every site under another user with suexec for example. Then every Customer has its own user with specified permissions only on its own folder.

A chroot is good but make some problems. The chroot is interesting if you plan to give the user an SSH entry to your system.

https://serverfault.com/questions/139826/apache-suexec-php-fpm-how-to-set-them-up